# How can I use Statsmodels' params parameter to pass my own coefficients to the predict method?

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

I'm trying to create graphs to visualize the confidence interval around each of the coefficients from a GLM. What I want to see is how my final prediction is affected when different values of a given coefficient are used while the remaining coefficients are held constant. For example, what would my prediction look like if I use the 2.5th percentile coefficient value for calendar year while keeping the remaining coefficients at their estimated value? How does that compare to using the 50th and the 97.5th percentiles for calendar year?

I got the estimated and 95% confidence interval values like so `poisson_results.params` and `poisson_results.conf_int()`. Looking at the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.predict.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.predict), I wanted to create an array like this:

````
new_params = ['0.266308','0.307143','0.694031','1.90103','2.729616','3.766581','4.317322','4.784669','5.566175','0.514219','0.120122','-0.122659','0.228447','0.179789','0.180528','0.152507','-0.009693','-0.01597','-0.046785','-0.081709','-0.087051','0.001042','-0.011786',]``` 

# converting the list to an array
new_params = np.array(new_params, dtype=float)


predicted_counts = poisson_results.predict(
    params=new_params,
    exog=df.select(
        pl.col(
            [
                "mortality_rate",
                "issue_age_clipped_45offset",
                "calendar_year_clipped_2012offset",
                "dur_cap20",
                "rate_up_group",
                "Factoring1",
                "qx",
                "RU_20_29",
                "RU_30_39",
                "RU_40_84",
                "imp_wtw",
                "attained_age_clipped_45offset",
                "att_Age",
            ]
        )
    ).to_pandas(),
    offset=df.select(pl.col("qx").log()).to_numpy().ravel()
)
````

After running the above snippet, I get this error:
`TypeError: predict() got multiple values for argument 'params'`.

How can I resolve this error?

Note, some of my features, such as rate_up_group, are categorical which is why there are more values in my array than there are features listed in my `exog` dataframe.

Also, note that this is written in the Polars syntax.

Edit:
Before the above code snippet, I fit my data to a model like this:

```
poisson_results = smf.glm(
    "mortality_rate ~ \
         + ...,
    data=df.to_pandas(),
    offset=offset,
    family=sm.families.Poisson(),
).fit(random_state=42)
```

Right after this is when I say

```
predicted_counts = poisson_results.predict(...)
```

to get the predicted values.

Comment: There is a difference between `results.predict` and `model.predict`. The results instance has the estimate params and it's predict only needs exog as arg which does not need to be provided for in-sample prediction.`model.predict` does not know what the prarameter estimates are and has `params` as first argument. If you want to predict using some predefined `params` than you need `model.predict(params, exog, ...)`

Comment: @Josef okay, that makes sense. Forgive my ignorance, but how do I call ```model.predict``` instead of ```results.predict```? I provided some more background about how I fit my model under the 'Edit' section of my comment. Thanks!

Comment: Either split the fit call from model creation, `model = GLM(...); results = model.fit(), model.predict(my_params)` or access the model through the results instance. `results.model.predict(my_params)`

Comment: Note, `model.predict` needs exog and other arrays as numpy arrays if those are provided. Only `result.predict` has data handling and transformation from formulas to create an the appropriate design matrix for predict. If no exog provided, i.e. `model.predict(my_params)`, then the model data is used.